# jQuery - triggering sequence of clicks won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click

hi this is my `code` http://jsfiddle.net/Xy4dF/1/

i have this part:

```
$('#top-user').on('click', function () {
        alert('1');
    });
    $('.user').on('click', function () {
        alert('2');
    });
```

now out of this code i want to trigger in sequence the 2 elements clicks

so i do:

```
$('#top-user').click(function () {
        $('.user').click();
    });
```

What is wrong? :O

Comment: what do you mean?? i get two alerts..and i think that is what you want rite ??

Comment: oh guys i see no alerts unbelievable, i'm on macosx FF 19 :/ i'm not kidding :/

Comment: @bipen you get TRIGGERED alerts? or you have to click to get alerts? i want to trigger ..

Comment: Something like this? [**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xy4dF/3/)

Comment: @Mr_Green that is ok just the problem is i can't bind trigger() with the click event , i mean i have to separate on() and click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following what you're after (I'm not 100% sure I've understood the question)

```
$(function () {

    $('#top-user').on('click', function () {
        alert('1');
    });
    $('.user').on('click', function () {
        alert('2');
    });


    $('#top-user').click(function () {
        $('.user').click();
    }).click();

});
```

The reasons your original code didn't work is that:

1. You had defined the event handlers but not triggered any on page load.
2. You need to define an event handler before you trigger it. This is because when triggering an event, JQuery fakes it by immediately calling the bound event handlers rather than managing to genuinely trigger the event at browser level.

Hope this helps